# How do I extract the payload data of a decoded JWT web token using PHP

Tags: php, json, jwt

I have a web token which decodes to the following:

```
{
 typ: "JWT",
 alg: "HS256"
}.
{
 iat: 1435688301,
 iss: "localhost",
 data: {
  user_id: 2
 }
}.
[signature]
```

I have this stored in a variable $data, and have no idea how to access the 'iat' value, or the 'user_id'. Can anyone help me out?

I've tried

```
$issuanceDate = $data['iat'];
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. I need the user id too, but that is nested in $data.data.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the decoded JWT a simple string? Perhaps you can also post code that is doing the decoding?

Comment: The decoded data appears to be an object of type stdClass, as the error I get back is "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array".

Comment: Can you please post the whole code in question? The part where you do the decoding and end up with the `$data` variable?

Comment: It's ok, I have solved it (I posted my answer below), thanks for taking the time to help anyway, much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved my problem. My solution:

The decoded token, '$data', returned from php-jwt::decode was an object, I simply cast it to an array using

```
$unencodedData = (array) $data;
```

and accessed the 'iat' field using

```
$issuedAt = $unencodedData['iat'];
```

Also, the object contained a nested object $data->data. To access this I cast the outer '$data' object to an array as above, and accessed the nested 'data' object like this:

```
$user_id = $unencodedData['data']->user_id;
```

Comment: Why cast to array rather than just use as object, as is intended?